# Python Pandas: classifying values in column and making a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

quick question.
I am trying to make a column in my df that classifies values in other columns. Take a look at my code below.

```
df['maker_grp'] = np.nan
for key in df[df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam|Mike")].index:
    df['maker_grp'][key] = 'Class1'
for key in df[df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")].index:
    df['maker_grp'][key] = 'Class2'
df['maker_grp'] = df.maker_grp.fillna('Class3')
```

It works perfectly, but I just have feelings that there is pythonic way of doing this with less processing. Help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam|Mike")
m2 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")

df['maker_grp'] = np.select([m1,m2], ['Class1','Class2'], default='Class3')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'maker_nm':['Sam 1','Joe 5','Paul 7','Mike 0']})
#print (df)

m1 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam|Mike")
m2 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")

df['maker_grp'] = np.select([m1,m2], ['Class1','Class2'], default='Class3')
print (df)
  maker_nm maker_grp
0    Sam 1    Class1
1    Joe 5    Class3
2   Paul 7    Class2
3   Mike 0    Class1
```

If many conditions `apply` with custom function should be faster:

```
import re

def f(x):
    p1 = re.compile("Sam|Mike")
    p2 = re.compile("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")
    if p1.match(x):
        return 'Class1'
    elif p2.match(x):
        return 'Class2'
    else:
        return 'Class3'

df['maker_grp'] = df['maker_nm'].apply(f)
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'maker_nm':['Sam 1','Joe 5','Paul 7','Mike 0']})

df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

#print (df)

In [117]: %%timeit
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = np.nan
     ...: for key in df[df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam|Mike")].index:
     ...:     df['maker_grp'][key] = 'Class1'
     ...: for key in df[df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")].index:
     ...:     df['maker_grp'][key] = 'Class2'
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = df.maker_grp.fillna('Class3')
     ...: 

In [118]: %%timeit
     ...: m1 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam|Mike")
     ...: m2 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy|John|Paul|Jay")
     ...: 
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = np.select([m1,m2], ['Class1','Class2'], default='Class3')
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.98 ms per loop

In [119]: %%timeit
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = df['maker_nm'].apply(f)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.38 ms per loop
```

**Caveat**:

Performance really depend on the data and number of conditions.

EDIT: For many conditions for check substrings is faster `apply`:

```
m1 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam", regex=False)
m2 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Mike", regex=False)
m3 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy", regex=False)
m4 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("John", regex=False)
m5 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Jay", regex=False)

df['maker_grp'] = np.select([m1,m2,m3,m4,m5], ['Class1','Class1', 'Class2','Class2','Class2'], default='Class3')
print (df)

def f(x):

    if 'Sam' in x:
        return 'Class1'
    elif 'Mike' in x:
        return 'Class1'
    elif 'Andy' in x:
        return 'Class2'
    elif 'John' in x:
        return 'Class2'
    elif 'Paul' in x:
        return 'Class2'
    elif 'Jay' in x:
        return 'Class2'  
    else:
        return 'Class3'

df['maker_grp'] = df['maker_nm'].apply(f)
print (df)
```

---

```
In [133]: %%timeit
     ...: m1 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Sam", regex=False)
     ...: m2 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Mike", regex=False)
     ...: m3 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Andy", regex=False)
     ...: m4 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("John", regex=False)
     ...: m5 = df['maker_nm'].str.contains("Jay", regex=False)
     ...: 
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = np.select([m1,m2,m3,m4,m5], ['Class1','Class1', 'Class2','Class2','Class2'], default='Class3')
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.79 ms per loop

In [134]: %%timeit
     ...: df['maker_grp'] = df['maker_nm'].apply(f)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop
```

Comment: It depends of data and number of condition, but if only 2 masks it is faster.

Comment: i think the best test it with real data, new solution was added for many conditions.

Comment: small tip: for a small number of conditions, i've found it is sometimes faster to do repeated `.str.contains('var', regex=False)` rather than a single `.str.contains('var1|var2', regex=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm I think this could be done pretty succinctly with pandas. This should be faster than iterating over each key with a for loop.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'maker_nm':['Sam 1','Joe 5','Paul 7','Mike 0']})

In [3]: conditions = {'Sam|Mike': 'Class1', 'Andy|John|Paul|Jay': 'Class2'}

In [4]: df.join(pd.concat([df[df.maker_nm.str.contains(c)].assign(maker_grp=conditions[c])
   ...:                    for c in conditions]).maker_grp).fillna('Class3')
   ...:                    
Out[4]: 
  maker_nm maker_grp
0    Sam 1    Class1
1    Joe 5    Class3
2   Paul 7    Class2
3   Mike 0    Class1
```